# I can't able to understand the following function in the solidity

Tags: solidity

```
function multiowned(address[] _owners, uint _required) {
    m_numOwners = _owners.length + 1;
    m_owners[1] = uint(msg.sender);
    m_ownerIndex[uint(msg.sender)] = 1;
    for (uint i = 0; i < _owners.length; ++i)
    {
        m_owners[2 + i] = uint(_owners[i]);
        m_ownerIndex[uint(_owners[i])] = 2 + i;
    }
    m_required = _required;
}
```

Can anyone help me understand the above solidity code and use of    m_owners[1] = uint(msg.sender); ?

Source code here https://github.com/ConsenSys/MultiSigWallet/blob/master/MultiSigWalletWithDailyLimit.sol

Comment: This code is not complete, we don't see the declarations of `m_numOwners` `m_owners`, `m_ownerIndex` and `m_required`

Comment: I have added link to the full source code. I am sorry

Comment: I believe what it's doing is making a fresh list of `_owners`  with `msg.sender` being added to the first index of this new map and all of the other address of `_owners` being pushed to +1 index in `m_owners`

Comment: @SaitejaKuruva The full source you linked to doesn't seem to relate to the code you shared. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The line in question:

```
m_owners[1] = uint(msg.sender);
```

stores `msg.sender` at index `1` of the array `m_owners`. Presumably the type of `m_owners` is an array (or `mapping`) of `uint`s rather than `address`es, so `msg.sender` is first cast to a `uint`.

`msg.sender` is the account that called the function `multiowned`.

Comment: But it's showing me the error when I am trying to run this code on remix. It says undeclared identifier   m_numOwners = _owners.length + 1;

Comment: You'd have to share the rest of the code. My guess would be that you didn't declare a variable called `m_numOwners` anywhere.

Comment: (The code you linked to in your question seems unrelated.)